# ¿Es una mejor práctica usar multipart/form-data en lugar de base64 al recibir archivos en un API?

Tags: base64, multipart

**Contexto**

He desarrollado un Web Api usando la tecnología .Net y una de las acciones es subir archivos de imágenes.

El API recibirá peticiones de aplicaciones móviles (Android y iOS).

El API debe cumplir con una de estas dos condiciones:

- Subir un archivo por cada petición usando `multipart/form-data`, es decir, el archivo viaja embedido directamente en la petición
- Subir un archivo por cada petición enviándolo en el *body* como un `string` codificado en `base64`

Ambas acciones funcionan y reciben el archivo (se manipula dependiendo del formato en que lo recibe el API).

**Pregunta**

¿Existe una ventaja o una mejor práctica al usar `multipart/form-data` en lugar de `base64` bajo el escenario expuesto?

Comment: `base64` es una forma de codificar que te agranda los datos hasta un 30% , `multipart/form-data` es parte del estándar `http` y permite enviar datos binarios, debido a eso `multipart` es mas rápido y consume menos ancho de banda.

Comment: base64 transforma datos binarios a una representación ASCII "imprimible", el espacio de 8 bits se reduce a 6 bits y se representa con letras y numeros (mas un par de simbolos), de ahi que el tamaño total aumente. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: multipart por el contrario permite enviar directamente los datos en binario (bytes de 8 bits) con el `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary` https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2

Comment: Vale, gracias por los datos, pero creo que mi pregunta aún no está del todo resuelta ;)

Comment: @JackNavaRow el método POST lo entiendo y lo sé, mi pregunta es básicamente sobre el escenario que expongo

Comment: siendo un API sobre http multipart es la que va, base64 es mas que nada usado en SMTP (que tiene un espacio de 7bits), o para pasarlo por url (menos el padding `=` que va a ser transformado a `%3D` y hay que decodificarlo aparte o calcularlo)

Comment: mmmmm mira depende, como dicen base64 te agrega un aprox de 25% etra de datos y en ocaciones los servidores (dependiendo del lenguaje) nisiquiera pueden transformar de base64, yo sugiero uses multipart solo que tendras que hacer algo que verifique la calidad de subida.
Pero mejor usa multipart esta soportada por el RFC 1867 (sabes que typo file es un archivo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`base64` es una forma de codificar que te agranda los datos hasta un 30% , `multipart/form-data` es parte del estándar `http` y permite enviar datos binarios, debido a eso `multipart` es mas rápido y consume menos ancho de banda

`base64` transforma datos binarios a una representación ASCII "imprimible", el espacio de 8 bits se reduce a 6 bits y se representa con letras y números (mas un par de símbolos), de ahí que el tamaño total aumente. 
Esto se explica muy bien en https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Ejemplo

> para esto usa un buffer de 24 bits: mete 3 bytes de 8 bits ( 8 x 3 = 24 ) y salen 4 "letras" de 6 bits cada una ( 6 x 4 = 24 )

como 4 es el 133% de 3 generalmente se dice que aumenta un 30% los datos de entrada.

`base64` es mas que nada usado en `SMTP` (que tiene un espacio de 7bits) es decir servidores y relays de email, o para pasarlo por url (menos el padding `=` que va a ser transformado a `%3D` y hay que decodificarlo aparte o calcularlo) un ejemplo común de `base64` en url es insertar archivos de imágenes (binario) en HTML, XML o CSS (sólo texto).

En API's simples puede tener sentido por ejemplo pasar por url un json encodificado en `base64` y así la URL contiene toda la info para generar la respuesta (aún así hay ciertos límites prácticos en cuanto al largo total de la URL).

`multipart` por el contrario permite enviar directamente los datos en binario (bytes de 8 bits) con el [`Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2)

Siendo un API sobre `http` y tenes que elegir entre ambos, `multipart/form-data` es la que va.

En caso de subida de archivos grandes con metadata [por ejemplo en el API de youtube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol) lo que proveen es un método adicional que separara el proceso en dos partes:
haces un POST con el metadata y recibis (en caso de que este todo ok) un `200` mas la `location` con el URI a donde hacer el PUT del archivo con el `content-length` y el `content-type`, esta URI incluye el id asignado al file asi podes resumir el upload en caso de red inestable, consultar si aun esta en proceso o si ya subió etc..

Answer (score 3):

`base64` es la conversion de los bytes a caracteres **ASCII**. No es recomendable que utilizes base64 ya que este agrega mas peso a la peticion. Por ejemplo el simple caracter `hola` que son 4 bytes convertido a base64 hacen **8 bytes**(hola en base64 es `aG9sYQ==`) y como acabas de decir que sera una aplicación android la que enviara la data, le estarías consumiendo mas datos de internet sin necesidad a los usuarios.

Otra cosa a tener en cuenta es que base64 tiene que ser decodificada en el servidor agregando esto mas proceso. Si envias un archivo de +10MB estarias tendrias que primero:

1. Convertir a base64 en el dispositivo: algo que es muy lento de por si.
2. Enviar la data al servidor:  lento y pesado por la cantidad de datos convertidos
3. Decodificarlos en el servidor : lento y proceso innecesario.

En el caso de multipart, este es parte del protocolo HTTP mientras que base64 no. Aunque no los comprime se asegura compatibilidad con todos lo servidores http y envia cualquier tipo de archivo.

Ventajas:

1. Soporte en todos los servidores HTTP
2. No agrega mas peso a la computacion de la subida de archivos
3. Se puede enviar cualquier archivo.